# Is there a way to normalize data with high kurtosis?

Tags: r, normalization

I have a vector that has a kurtosis of 2.95 (which is pretty high, Leptokurtic). Following is a sample of that data:

```
x = c(6.819, 8.948, 0, 67.556, -40.785, -18.951, -29.151, 1.008, 
0, 18.034, -6.631, 6.294, 0.643, -28.921, 0, -2.133, -44.348, 
-87.488, 7.063, 0, -74.428, -16.361, 50.963, -32.431, -82.233, 
-26.953, -48.475, 64.043, 0, 1.576, -2.728, -5.9, -63.059, -1.061, 
-15.018, -58.119, -32.092, 5.329, -19.968, 38.822, 66.897, 0, 
-2.579, 82.696, 42.745, 79.677, 2.522, -11.475, 1.019, 2.719, 
-3.634, -7.975, 0, 1.873, 21.732, -10.217, -24.002, -76.049, 
35.045, 27.22, -71.366, 16.293, -48.762, 65.481, 66.615, -19.616, 
6.016, 59.722, 88.235, 10.1, 0, -4.598, 5.446, 56.909, 0, -24.827, 
0, 6.487, 0, 63.315, 28.397, 9.433, 19.085, 0, 6.591, -22.643, 
32.235, -12.535, -1.787, 56.157, 68.819, 0, -21.936, 38.695, 
-79.006, 24.888, -5.187, 10.368, -68.191, 0, -22.171, -78.783, 
-14.119, 54.084, -13.597, 26.669, 0, -18.402, 80.309, -12.652, 
1.801, -69.946, -87.67, -19.586, 38.085, -21.031, -36.957, 1.357, 
0.17, 47.407, -59.598, 66.125, 10.97, 6.33, -38.837, 1.868, 38.169, 
-46.662, -32.255, 25.816, 14.432, -18.57, -0.456, -0.638, 31.07, 
72.794, 52.957, 13.858, -18.885, 0, -13.488, 11.689, 1.618, 19.373, 
-57.526, 0, -0.655, 36.308, 50.231, 0.048, -80.157, 0, -64.805, 
-70.864, 0.813, 52.143, -4.989, 42.166, 7.397, 87.437, -17.897, 
-0.877, 68.363, 47.315, -2.181, 2.699, 36.278, 0, -2.924, 71.56, 
74.406, -46.071, 56.158, 1.44, 0, 0, 0, -3.233, 37.084, -85.189, 
0, -16.137, -84.499, -12.67, -14.117, 0, 23.757, -58.299, -34.956, 
0.402, 0, -67.585, -14.314, -73.426, 23.158, 1.782, 0, 4.399, 
18.871, -6.929)
```

[image: data with high kurtosis]

1. Is there a way to normalize this data?
2. Since this data range between -90 to 90, the normalized data should be in a similar range and should not change vastly, i.e. the range should not be changed to -1 to 1 or -20 to 20 etc...

I have tried using `atan(X)`, `1/x`, `log(x)`, and many other transformational techniques but they all tend to increase the skewness. Is there a way to normalize this data without skewing it?

I am sure there must be an easy solution to this.

Comment: What is your goal? Why are you normalizing? It seems like your data has quite a few 0s - that might be part of the issue.

Comment: My goal is to compare this vector with another vector in which is almost perfectly normalized and is a similar range of -90 to 90.

Comment: Compare in what way? What is the goal of the comparison?  What are you *actually* trying to do/understand?

Comment: I am trying to find the relation of these two vectors which (theoretically) are supposed to be highly correlated, however, due to kurtosis, the relationship cannot be established.

Comment: Which two vectors? You only show a single set of data.  Honestly this really sounds like an XY problem http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: These vectors are actually the angles of two time-series that are correlated and move together. However, due to differences in their scales, the angles differ vastly.

Comment: Yes this definitely sounds like an XY problem.  I don't think you need to normalize this one vector as much as you need to find a better way of attacking your *actual* problem.

Comment: I am sure what I am doing is not an XY problem. Normalizing a variable to find a relationship between two variables cannot be seen as a strange problem.

Comment: Well you said that the series seem to move together. But then you transform both of them and now they don't appear to be moving together. That isn't a normalization issue - that's a transformation issue.  Two cars can appear to be basically side by side on the highway but one could have cruise control on and the other could constantly be changing between some gas and then braking. If we compare their positions they appear correlated. If we compare their acceleration they don't appear correlated at all.  Transformations can drastically change things and that's what you've done.

Comment: In the car metaphor, this study is actually about the relationship between a car's velocity and pressure on the accelerator.

Comment: Ok fine but it's the same issue.  My main point here is that you're asking about normalizing a single vector when that does not seem to be the actual problem you're trying to solve.  I'm saying that it's probably the wrong approach as well. That makes it a XY problem to me - you're trying to solve the normalization issue because you think it's the route you need to go to solve the larger problem but I don't think it is.  Honestly it sounds like what would be more appropriate is for you to post your larger issue at https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: taking a guess, have you considered a non-parametric correlation measure like the Spearman rank correlation?

Comment: Since one of the variables is perfectly normalized and the other is not, I have not used the non-parametric correlation test. Or can I? Right now, I am using Pearson's correlation after normalizing the vector.

Comment: Yup - XY problem.  Read up on Spearman correlation.

Comment: Indeed, it helped me understand my problem a little better. Thanks Ben and Dason! Spearman is the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may not be what you want but you can almost always *perfectly* normalize a distribution (if there are no ties) using a *normal scores transformation*:

```
xq <- qnorm(rank(x)/(length(x)+1), mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x))
plot(sort(x),sort(xq))
hist(xq)
qqnorm(xq)
```

The new range is (-99.2, 99.6) (the old range was +/- 88).

If you need to change the range you could do it as follows:

```
newmin + (newmax-newmin)*scale(xq, center=min(qx), scale=diff(range(xq)))
```

but as suggested in the comments this may not actually be the right approach to solve your broader problem.